# Unable to install Visual Studio 2010 Professional on my virtualbox

Tags: installation, virtualbox, visual-studio-2010

I have tried so many times to install Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition on my  Virtual machine in Windows Server 2008 Environment.I have find following error log file.

[01/07/11,22:42:55] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.

[01/07/11,22:42:56] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: f:\vs_setup.msi

---

Comment: Based on the error log Your `vs_setup.msi` is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I have install VS2010 on my host machine using samse copy of setup it has been installed successfully. but when i try to install on my guest i.e. WS2008 on VirtualBox. It is showing error. I have also tried VS2008 SP1 but that showing some compability issue and not getting install.

Comment: It sounds to be connected to WS2008 do you have all released updates installed?

Comment: No actually i am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (180 days Trial Version) in my VirtualBox 4.2.10 to just learn installation of MS Dynamics CRM 4.0.